# Resizing background image in XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: image, background

Our SharePoint guy migrated us from 2013 to 2016 and left.  There's a web part that I've determined is a XsltListViewWebPart.

The background image for each tile is now using like the upper left 70% of the background image.  Of course this is a hot priority for management even though they haven't hired a replacement SharePoint guy and I don't know it.  I resized the source images and that didn't help at all.  It's like a scaling thing??

This is at the top of our home page so I'm really gun shy messing with it, so I appreciate any help.